# Google Sheets: count how many cells in a range exactly match a corresponding range

Tags: google-sheets

I have a row of cells, let's just say A1:K:1 and I'm trying to count how many times each cell in this range matches the corresponding cell in a range below it, eg A3:K3. So, if A1=A3 that's 1. If B1=B3 that's 2. If C1=/=C3, don't count it. If D1=D3 we're at 3 total. And so on.

I thought wrapping `countif` around an `IF` function would do it, but neither my `countif` function or `if` seem to be behaving as I expected.

I even just tried doing a basic `countif` A1=A3 + B1=B3 etc until K1=K3 but that didn't even work.

Any and all help is extremely appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following has the desired behaviour:

`=COUNTIF(ARRAYFORMULA(EQ(A1:K1, A2:K2)), TRUE)`

There might be a simpler solution, but this is what first came to mind!

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you so much. This worked so perfectly. Never used EQ before, so now I've got something new to study. Can't thank you enough :)